# Determine If Signalr Scale Out Is Necessary

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am having trouble wrapping my head around whether or not my scenario will require scale out. I have a process in a windows service that pushes messages to a hub hosted in a web app via the signalr .net client. These are user specific messages and are distributed using the Client(connectionid) approach. If this is deployed in a web farm scenario will I need to use a scale out approach? When a user joins I am storing that connection info in the database. I store the url of the webserver and connectionid so I can target that when I publish messages from the windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this if it is an option.
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

Louis